# Is there a faster way to compare items across lists than to call multiple ajax queries?

Tags: javascript, ajax, list, sharepoint

I'm working on a `Sharepoint` site and have a JS function that deletes items from a series of Sharepoint lists if the user associated with that item (1 user can have multiple items) is no longer has access to the site. Unfortunately, because the total list of users is split into 3 different Sharepoint lists, this means I have to make 3 ajax calls per item to see if the user exists in any of them. This causes the overall process to take a really long time to execute, although it does work as intended. Is there a faster way to do this comparison? I should mention I only have access to the sharepoint lists, not the sql database they are uploaded from and cannot change the organization of the lists.

Here is my current code (changed some variable names for sake of project privacy):

```
  function clearItems(){
    var tempListname;
    var modalLists = ["CList","AList","VList","WList","GList","LList"];
    for(i = 0; i < modalLists.length; i++){
        tempListname = modalLists[i];
        urlTEMP = "../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + tempListname + "')/items?$top=10";
        clearOldStudents(modalLists[i], urlTEMP);
    }
}

var counter = 0;
function clearOldItems(listname, url){
    $.ajax({ //Starts the ajax call
       url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            while(counter<data.d.results.length){
                console.log(data.d.results[counter].username);
                if(!isInES(data.d.results[counter].username) && 
                     !isInMS(data.d.results[counter].username)){
                    getItemC("userlis3",data.d.results[counter].username);
                    if(resultsClub[0] == null){
                        if(listname == "CList"){
                            deleteCItem(data.d.results[counter].Id);
                        }
                        else if(listname == "AList"){
                            deleteAItem(data.d.results[counter].Id);
                        }
                        else if(listname == "VList"){
                            deleteVItem(data.d.results[counter].Id);
                        }
                        else if(listname == "WList"){
                            deleteWItem(data.d.results[counter].Id);
                        }
                        else if(listname == "GList"){
                            deleteGItem(data.d.results[counter].Id);
                        }
                        else if(listname == "LList"){
                            deleteCItem(data.d.results[counter].Id);
                        }
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
            counter=0;

             if (data.d.__next) {
                url = data.d.__next;
                clearOldStudents(listname, url);
            } 
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

the `isInMS`, `isInES`, and `getItemC` functions all make `ajax` calls to check if the student is in one of the 3 lists of users

Comment: Do you have access to the backend code?

Comment: I guess the api is given by sharepoint @RyanWilson

Comment: @L4B0MB4 Good catch. I'm sleepy today.

Comment: @RyanWilson as L4B0MB4 noted a lot of it is given by sharepoint so I guess it depends what you mean

Comment: @L4B0MB4 If all your calls are to an API, is there any way you could combine the calls into one server side method? Then just make one ajax call per person?

Comment: @RyanWilson I don't have access to the server unfortunately

Comment: @carsonnitro You could look into doing the 3 calls to the API in parrallel and incorporate `Promise.all()` documentation here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) this would cut down on some of the time.

Comment: Call the lists that hold the permissions and consolidate the names into an object/array. Then you locally have who has access to which list. Call the lists and compare it to the appropriate object/array you just created. This should limit your calls to 3 for getting the permissions, then however many lists you have to search through.